# How to record reaction time if event is not happening jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I have my function that records the reaction time from the display of the stimulus (word or picture) until the keypress.
But if there is no key pressed, the reaction time will be NaN, yet I'd like it to run through until the next stimulus appears (here after 1000ms), so that the reaction even if no key is pressed is then equal to 1000ms:

How could I record the milliseconds until 1000ms if there is no keypress event?

```
var t1;
var i = 0;
$(function(){
    var timeout = 0;
    function showNext() {
        t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
            if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
            var new_word = stim[Math.floor((Math.random()*stim.length)+1)].name;
            $("#abc").text(new_word);
            } else {
            var new_img =  stim[Math.floor((Math.random()*stim.length)+1)].path;
            $("#abc").empty();
            var prox_img = $('<img id="abcimg" height="300px" width="300px">');
            prox_img.attr('src', new_img);
            prox_img.appendTo('#abc');
            }
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){showNext()}, 1000);
    }
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
            if ($(e.target).is('input, textarea') || i > 10) {
                return;
            };
        i++;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (e.which === 97 || e.which === 108 || e.which === 32) {
              setTimeout(function(){showNext();}, 100);
            var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
              var reac_time = t2-t1;
              $("#time").text(reac_time);
                }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the start of `showNext()`, just check if the displayed time is `NaN`, and set it to `1000`.

```
function showNext() {
     if( isNaN($("#time").text()) ){
         $("#time").text("1000");
     }
     //... your other code
}
```

See [w3Schools isNaN()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Any idea how I could detach the flow of the function (10 times here) from the key presses, so that there will be 10 stimulus presentations, 10 reaction times, completely regardless the key presses? Or should I ask this in a new question? Thanks anyway.